# Examples of complete bases in spherical coordinates

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, orbital-motion, hydrogen, special-functions

The set of functions of a three-dimensional harmonic oscillator is a complete basis.

The functions of the 3D harmonic oscillator in the case l=0:

```
Psi[r_, n_] := (-1)^n *Exp[-1/2 *r^2] *Sqrt[2 *n!/Gamma[n + 3/2]]* 
   LaguerreL[n, 1/2, r^2];
```

n = 0, 1, 2, ...

Could you suggest any other complete bases (written in spherical coordinates)?